# ¿Por qué no puedo mantener el estado del control imageButton? - ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un ImageButton dentro de un DataList que al darle click se agrega una clase a sí mismo (lo que en realidad sería al `input` del tipo image cuando está renderizado).
El problema es que agrega la clase pero la pierde al recibir la respuesta del servidor, estuve tratando de controlaro con el `EnableViewState` y `ViewStateMode` pero no funcionó.

Código .aspx con el script que utilizo para agregar la clase.

```
<%@ Page Title="ValidarImagenes" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ValidarImagenes.aspx.cs" Inherits="GD.ModuloParametros.ValidarImagenes" ValidateRequest="false" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
            <asp:Accordion ID="accValidarImagenes" runat="server" FadeTransitions="True" FramesPerSecond="40" Width="100%"
                        TransitionDuration="200" RequireOpenedPane="false" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
                         ContentCssClass="accordionContent" HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeader_selected">
            <Panes>
                <asp:AccordionPane ID="accPaneValidarImagenes" runat="server">
                    <Header>
                        <div class="accordionTitulo">
                            <span class="TituloFiltros" id="TituloFiltros">
                                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:GD, TituloValidarImagenesClientes%>"></asp:Literal>
                            </span> - Seleccione las imágenes que desea validar. 
                        </div>
                    </Header>
                    <Content>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:DataList ID="dlImagenes" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" HorizontalAlign="Center" PagedControlID="dlImagenes" CellSpacing="10" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" OnItemCommand="dlImagenes_ItemCommand"> <%----%>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgValidarImagenes" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="150px" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("imagen") %>' OnClientClick="modImg(this)" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' CssClass="previewImg" EnableViewState="true" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>                                                                                                    
                                </asp:DataList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dlImagenes"/>
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        <div style="text-align:end; padding:10px;" id="divBtnValidar">
                             <asp:Button ID="btnValidar" runat="server" Text="Validar" CssClass="lnkDocumento" OnClick="btnValidar_Click" />
                        </div>
                    </Content>
                </asp:AccordionPane>
            </Panes>
        </asp:Accordion><br />
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
    <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<!--Imagen Modal-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
    // Obtengo el modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");


    function modImg(input) {

        if ($(input).hasClass('clicked')) {
            $(input).removeClass('clicked');
            //código doble click para mostrar la imagen en modal
            var src = $(input).attr('src');
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = src;
            captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }
        else {
            $(input).addClass('clicked');
            setTimeout(function sto() {
                if ($(input).hasClass('clicked')) {
                    $(input).removeClass('clicked');
                    //código click para seleccionar la imagen
                    $(input).toggleClass('imagenSeleccionada');
                }
            }, 400);
        }
    }
    // Obtengo el <span> para cerrar
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // Cuando el usuario de click en <span> que es la "x", cierro la ventana modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

</script>
```

Comment: no entiendo lo que quieres hacer, el codigo y variables del front end no se preserva después de un post/refresh/redirect y aqui solo veo javascript

Comment: Quiero mantener el estado del control después del postback, el js lo usé para agregar una clase la cual se pierde luego del postback, y yo quiero mantenerla

Comment: Entiende, el Front end no se preserva, tus clases son clases de estilo de CSS, lo unico que se preserva despues de un postback es lo que mantienes en el back end, y eso lo manejas desde c#

Comment: Ok, desde el front lo hice y funciona bien para Firefox y Chrome pero en IE 11 se me hace mucho mas lento el proceso de agregar la clase, por eso es que intenté usar javascript y la verdad que es la primera que vez que intento hacer esto de esta manera. Hay alguna forma de hacerlo desde javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalemente lo resolví cancelando el Postback desde el evento `OnClientClick` del `ImageButton`. En la función sólo tenía que agregar `return false;` y esto cancela el Postback. Al no producirse el Postback, se mantiene la clase que agregué al botón.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgValidarImagenes" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="150px" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("imagen") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' CssClass="previewImg" EnableViewState="true"  OnClientClick="modImg(this); return false;" />
```

Dejo este [enlace](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/04/aspnet-javascript-alert-y-confirm-como.html) de donde obtuve la respuesta y tiene algunos ejemplos de como tratar con Javascript desde el codebehind, quizá a alguien le pueda servir.

Comment: El return false funciona para no llamar al servidor... en ese caso yo preferiría usar controles html sin el "runat=server", pero supongo que asi tambien funciona.

Answer (score 1):

para hacer un toggle button necesitaras una bandera desde tu backend

```
 bool presionado; 

 Load() //el load de la pagina en el backend
      if(!Page.IsPostback) //solo inicializamos la bandera cuando no sea un postback
      {
           presionado = false;
      }

 buttonclick() //el evento de buttonclick en el backend
      {
          presionado = !presionado;
      }
```

en el front-end

```
//tienes que invocar esto en el page load o ready de tu pagina. 
var presionado= '<%= presionado %>'; //sacamos el valor del lado del servidor
 if (presionado) { 
        $(input).removeClass('clicked');
        //código doble click para mostrar la imagen en modal
        var src = $(input).attr('src');
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
    else {
        $(input).addClass('clicked');
        setTimeout(function sto() {
            if ($(input).hasClass('clicked')) {
                $(input).removeClass('clicked');
                //código click para seleccionar la imagen
                $(input).toggleClass('imagenSeleccionada');
            }
        }, 400);
    }
```

Comment: Excelente, con esto puedo entrar al script, dame un tiempo que acomodo el código porque tengo que hacer la selección correcta del botón en el script y ya te digo como me fue. Gracias!!

Comment: nota, si no necesitas ejecutar codigo desde el backend the recomendaria cambiar tus asp:button por input:type button, o por un simple html image con evento onclick para llamar a tus funciones de javascript. 

Lo importante es no hacer un postback, y en caso que lo hagas, utiliza el metodo "Get", de esta manera los parametros seran enviados a al URL de manera que los podras leer desde javascrip tambien

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios y tu ayuda @Mike, lo voy a tener en cuenta para seguir trabajando sobre este tema. Por lo pronto el problema lo pude resolver desde el HTML.